# How to use ng-app and ng-controller for many pages?

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-controller, ng-app

I'm stuck in CRUD Operations in AngularJS.

1. `index.html`. on this page on body I am using `ng-app` and `ng-controller`.
2. `offer_letter_dashboard.php` and
3. `termination_dashboard.php` on this page I am writing script for adding and fetching data.

I am using the same script on both the pages for fetching data. Here is the script:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/companyJson.php")
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;
        });
        getInfo();
        function getInfo(){
            $http.post('gettermination.php').success(function(data){
                $scope.details = data;
            })
        }    
    });
</script>
```

Right now only the first page can retrieve data. Only the first page's script is working fine. And it applies for termination's page too.

Comment: Suggest you to read more on `ngRoutes`

Comment: ohk bro thanks for reply @KarthikVU

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple instances of the same controller on different pages with ng-app and ng-controller.
If you have multiple controllers in the same app, you can use ng-route or ui-router to link the pages
If you want to use the same script to make requests to multiple urls you can use a function in your script passing the url

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) 
  {
      var getData=function(url){
         $http.get(url)
         .then(function(response){
         $scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;});
         getInfo();
         function getInfo(){
         $http.post('gettermination.php').success(function(data)
          {
            $scope.details = data;
          })
        }
      } 

  });
```

Comment: im using same controller for multiple pages. so no need to use ng-route right bro??

Comment: if that's the case then you just need to use ng-app and ng-controller on each page

Comment: if i have used it on all pages with same ng-app and controller . there are total 7 pages and 7 tables for each . in this condition only my last page's script it running on all pages.

Comment: does each of your pages make a request to a different url?

Comment: Then it's better if you enclose each of them in a function and pass the url as a variable. I'll edit my original answer

Comment: ohk bro i'll create a single page for all scripts. thanks